# how to open a specific tab in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have `<a>` tag  `<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"> click </a>`
if I click on it, it will open stack overflow in new tab. if I again click on it, again stack overflow will open in new tab. 
But, how many times I click on the `<a>` tag if the same URL is already in the browser tab it just have to open that only, not new tab. Is it possible? if yes how?

Comment: well _blank opens a new tab so use a named target

Comment: give name to target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `target` attribute to another value, like this:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="foo">link 1</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="bar">link 2</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="foo">link 3</a>
```

The first link will keep opening the same tab every time you click it.
Same goes for the second link, but their context is separate, i.e. when you click the first one and then the second one, you end up with two tabs. But no more, even if you click multiple times. The third link will use the same tab as the first link. Try it!

Comment: I am today days old when I found out target value can be more than “_blank”.

Comment: It can, it was originally meant for frames! :)

Comment: And there I am making JS scripts to do the same :D. Good info...

Comment: Guys, remember that `target` also allows to open in `<iframe>`. But I don't this the behavior in my answer is a standard. But it has always worked.

Comment: @RoboRobok my word... I haven’t used them since 2004.